# Mysql 5.5 with hibernate 4 order by is inconsistent

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are using hibernate 4 and mysql 5.5.x with Innodb as our default engine. We have a stored proc that returns some rows by joining a view and a temporary **MYISAM** temp table that gets created inside the stored proc. 
The stored proc gets called using hibernate session factory and session and ScrollableResultSet. It returns a list of object arrays. 
Here is the sample query

```
SELECT 
col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM view1 v 
JOIN temptable1 t on t.id = v.id
ORDER BY intcol DESC, varcharcol
```

Here is the problem...
For rows that have the same **intcol** value, the secondary order by on the **varcharcol** is not working properly, they are being returned in jumbled order.

Example rows being returned

```
Row1, 10, 'foo'
Row2 , 10, 'bar'
Row3, 10, 'foo'
Row4, 10, 'foo'
Row5, 10, 'bar'
```

Has anybody encountered a similar problem?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found out something that can guide you.

For example, you can't use a variable in order by clause. You have to concate a value and use the concatenated value after.

Like this:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT X FROM BOOKS " . $orderby);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not using any variables in my order by. It is an acutual column name, i just called in intcol for illustration purposes